# storing character pointers in vectors, C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

```
struct temp
{
   char *a;
};

vector<struct temp> array;

void AddData(char *p1, char *p2)
{
   struct temp t1;
   t1.a=new char[strlen(p1)+1];
   strcpy(t1.a,p1);
   array.push_back(t1);
}
```

Now if I call everytime `AddData()`, there would be memory leak, if I call `delete[]` on `t1.a` after `push_back()` I would get garbage when I later print vector array. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Don't use raw pointers to resources like that. There is no other safe way to do this.

Comment: Store the strings by value (`std::string`) or use `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: if u need it later then why delete now? just wait until all usage and then delete all from vector. But best to use `string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're putting the pointer to your array into the `vector`, not the array contents.  So if you `delete` that pointer immediately after inserting the object into the vector, accessing it later will be undefined.  In order to avoid a memory leak, you need to delete the array when you remove its reference from the vector, and not before.

There are several ways that you could go about doing this.  For the specific case of a character array holding a string, you could use `std::string` instead.  Another approach would be to add a copy constructor and assignment operator to `temp` which copies the array into a new one owned by the `temp` in the vector, and then add a destructor to `temp` that deletes the array (or better yet, use a smart pointer such as std::unique_ptr that handles cleanup for you).

Comment: You would need an assignment operator too, otherwise you will end up with double deletes.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Thanks for pointing that out.  I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This code is very bad coding style. However it does not leak any memory *per se*.  The memory you allocated with `new[]` is still being pointed to by an element of the global vector; so the rest of the program is able to `delete[]` that memory later on.

(It's not the same as if you wrote for example `char *foo = new char[20]; return;` - those 20 bytes would be leaked).

In case you didn't realize, what happens is that both the vector element and the local copy `t1` contain a pointer; both of those pointers point to the same block of allocated memory. There is no "magic" allocation of another memory block or anything.

You shouldn't call `delete[]` after doing `push_back`. That would delete the memory which is still being pointed to by a pointer in the vector; causing undefined behaviour when you go to use the vector.

In general you should do one `delete[]` for each `new[]`; and in this code, the time to do it would be when you have finished with the vector; at that point you can clear the vector and delete the pointers that were in it.

NB. Of course it would be better to abandon this approach entirely and use containers which manage their own memory, as everyone else has suggested.  Doing it this way it is very easy to inadvertently `delete[]` memory twice, or not delete it at all.

Comment: @juanchopanza lol, I never thought to work around that stupid un-downvote restriction by editing it myself

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to manage the memory by `new/delete` and you can use `std::string` for strings.

```
struct temp
{
   std::string a;
};

std::vector<temp> array;

void AddData(char *p1, char *p2)
{
   temp t1;

   t1.a = std::string(p1);

   array.push_back(t1);
}
```

Moreover, when you `delete` a pointer it just de-allocates the memory and calls its destructor (if it has one). You have garbage because you have no allocated memory, try to remove the item from the vector.

If you don't want to remove the item, you can set the pointer to `0` after de-allocating it. Now, you know that the pointer points to nothing and you can avoid de-referencing it.